# Encountering "Validation of viewstate MAC failed"

Tags: asp.net, amazon-ec2, viewstate

We have an **ASP.NET 4.0** web working on a **Windows Server 2008 R2** (installed on an Amazon ec2 instance). Every now and then, our users receive an error like this:

```
Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Source: System.Web

StackTrace:    
at System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowMacValidationError(Exception inner, String persistedState)
at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString)
at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.LoadHistoryState(String serverState)
at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

TargetSite: Void ThrowMacValidationError(System.Exception, System.String)

System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster. ---> System.Web.UI.ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 
Client IP: Some IP
Port: 49314
Referer: http://www.xxxx.com/xxxxxxx
Path: /xxxxxxx
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36
ViewState: /wEXAQUMVmVyUHJvZHVjdG9zBQxQVkQgQVNDIzQjMTCkifeeYf3AT+qOX2HL/wiZX7nF6E2sPjS/OhlzF+pfNg==

at System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowMacValidationError(Exception inner, String persistedState)
at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString)
at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.LoadHistoryState(String serverState)
at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

We have searched for a solution and nothing seems to work. We've added a machine key and the error appears too. This error started to appear when we moved everthing to EC2. On our own old dedicated server there was no problem.

**NOTE: Setting enableEventValidation="false" is not an option.**

Answer (score 0):

this usually happens when you create dynamnic controls and you do not set the same ID each time your recreate them (you recreate them with every Page_Init, I hope). Another cause for the problem may be when you modify some controls on the server (e.g., clear a controls container) but this change does not travel to the client (i.e., it happens during a partial postback). The next time the page is POST-ed, the client will send viewstate and controls' values (e.g., inputs) that do not exist on the server anymore.
Thus, look for such logic in your page and/or try to disable AJAX to see if there is a difference.

Another option is to disable ViewState for as many controls as possible, it is rarely needed anyway.

Yet another option is to store the ViewState on the server instead of in a hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

as @rdmptn mentioned there are many reasons behind this scenario.
1 of them is Application Pool recycling.
If user is busy on website and application pool gets recycled then server will not find posted back viewstate/session and throws error. this is generally happens when we have not explicitly provided machine.

So the solution is provide machine key in web.config..
< machinekey validationkey="xxx" decryptionkey="xxx" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />

for more details please look into http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/464873/Validation-of-viewstate-MAC-failed

You can generate machine key from following URL

http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

and put that machinekey element in web.config

Comment: We've added a machine key, as I told previously, and the problem is still there.

Comment: Then I guess 3rd or 5th Solution on above given link( http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/464873/Validation-of-viewstate-MAC-failed) may work for you as yo have moved to another environment.